# Multiple push channels (WNS) for a single app?

Tags: wcf, windows-runtime, push-notification, channel, azure-mobile-services

Basically I have two distinct services I wish to use (my own WCF back end service) and an Azure Mobile Service that both use push notifications. They're associated with the same app in the windows store.

In my code, I have two separate modules that call.

```
var newChannel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

This all seemed like fun and games and unless I horribly misread the documentations, having multiple channels for one App should be ok.

However, when I sent a notification from the WCF service to the app, it went to the AMS handler and naturally threw an invalid format exception given that I'm using my own Raw push notification format.

So my question is this; do I need to re-engineer the structure to have only one push channel handler that will divide the messages based on their format to the correct handlers, or what is the methodology I need to follow in order to get multiple push channels for a single app?

Comment: Ok first clear me you have two services. And you need to communicate with the app using both  ???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the only formats being supported in wns push notification us either e xml based format or the json data format. If while communicating to the wns you are sending some other format then then it is bound to exceptions.  ? Go through the demo from the link
[Push notification sample](http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/12/implementing-windows-8-push-notifications-an-example/)

if this does not solve the problem then please leave a comment behind

Comment: I might've formatted my question poorly and I apologize. My problem was merely that I am using a Raw format push notifications of two types in two separate services. I have written my own parsers for both of these and the problem is that after I have registered 2 channels, when I receive a push notification, it goes to the wrong handler. I solved this by simply having one handler and forwarding the messages by type to the corresponding libraries.

My initial question should, in short, be: Can one app register two separate push channels using PushNotificationChannelManager?

Comment: No you will get a single push channel using the push notification manager per device. The channel url u get is same for an app every time u call it and is provided by wns.